# Replacing text using regex expression in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to find words starting with `stop.` and extract the string that follows the word. Each string should be in a new line.

Also the results file should not have any duplicates.

**Example file:**

```
example regex stop.variant1
stop stop.variant_2 examplestop
stopstopvariant
stop.variant_@_3
```

**Result:**

```
variant1
variant_2
variant_@_3
```

Comment: See [`pattern-matching` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pattern-matching/info) info: *DO NOT USE THIS TAG FOR REGULAR EXPRESSION QUESTIONS, USE [regex] INSTEAD; similarly, for pattern matching (globbing) in POSIX-like shells, use [glob]*

Comment: This is not programming related. https://superuser.com/  would probably be a better place to ask this question.

Comment: @jingx: Questions about regex and Notepad++ are welcome here.

Comment: Find: `[\S\s]+?(variant.*?\d)`  replace with: `$1\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `.*?(\bstop\.variant\S*)`
- Replace with: `$1\n`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
.*?                 # 0 or more any character
(                   # group 1
    \b              # word boundary
    stop\.variant   # literally
    \S*             # 0 or more non spaces
)                   # end group
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]